# What is the replacement for performance.navigation.type in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, router, navigateurl

I have this code in order to know if the page is reload by the user, unfortunately is deprecated. I want to know if angular has this approach.

```
if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
   console.log('is refreshed')
}

if (performance.navigation.type === 0) {
   console.log('the user is arrived')
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not specific to Angular, but this API has been replaced by the [PerformanceNavigationTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) one, which also has a [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type) property, but which returns a string instead of a numerical code.

However I just noticed that Chrome won't expose this for iframes, which will always output `"navigate"`.

> The following snippet won't work in Chrome, please try [this plnkr instead](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ib3oLM6fMAQ7n5Utqme?p=preview), in external view.

```js
const entries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

console.log( entries.map( nav => nav.type ) );

rel.onclick = e => location.reload();
```

```html
<button type="button" id="rel">reload</button>
<a href="404">go to 404 (come back with your browser's back button)</a>
```

Comment: Nice one, though mind that "This is an experimental technology, expect behavior to change in the future."

Answer (score 16):

`performance.navigation` was deprecated. To get navigation type you can use `getEntriesByType`

Example

```
console.log(performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type)
```

The `type` value can be

```
enum NavigationType {
    "navigate",
    "reload",
    "back_forward",
    "prerender"
};
```

See more: https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#sec-performance-navigation-types

Answer (score 5):

I want to add that running:

```
performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
```

returns an empty array in Safari

Comment: same issue for me in Safari, were you able to find a solution?